# Get element by child using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a child value in Firebase but, i have no idea how do it.

**example:**

```
/users/{some_user_id_here}/{rank_id_here}
/users/1866/4
```

I need get all users when u rank id is 4, for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
        var userQuery = firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('rank').equalTo(4);
        userQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
              var childData = childSnapshot.val();
              console.log(childKey);
              console.log(childData);
           });
        });
```

Have a look at the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events